# Ubuntu-Tweak tweaks get ignored after reboots

Tags: 12.04, workspaces, login-screen, ubuntu-tweak

When I set the corners to reveal workspaces/windows, It stops working after a couple of reboots. Why? In addition, my chosen Login screen lasts for 1 second during login and reverts to current wallpaper. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. So I found the solution here:
[Scale plugin keeps forgetting hot corner settings on restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140759)
Ubuntu-Tweak use compiz for this tweak. So the problem is the same.

Copied from there:

> 1. Run `gconf-editor` from Terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
> 2. Navigate to apps → compiz-1 → general → screen0 → options → active_plugins
> 3. Move "Scale" to the bottom of the list.
> 4. Move "Expo" to bottom right above "Scale" and underneath Unityshell.

Comment: There is no "compiz-1 > general > screen0 > options > active_plugins", just "apps > gconf-editor."

Comment: @Lexible man, this is old. Ubuntu doesn't work with compiz anymore. It was used with Unity.

Comment: Happy to reverse vote, but need to edit answer first. :)