# Scale plugin keeps forgetting hot corner settings on restart

Tags: compiz

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity, which I suppose uses Compiz as well. I have Compiz Settings Manager, and make the top left and bottom left corners of my screen activate the "Scale" (like Exposé) function to scale and show all windows.

The problem is that when I restart the computer, the hot corners **no longer do anything**. I have to go back into compiz settings manager, delete the hot corner option, and then set it again. Something seems to be overriding or deleting the compiz hot corner setting on restart.

**Update**: Sometimes, the setting loses its footing even while the computer is running. I haven't figured out yet what triggers it.

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo T410s. This problem also occures when I release the notebook from the docking station where a second tft is connected to. There is already a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/999939

Comment: I was having the issue too. Try opening the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and entering `compiz --replace` . It replaces any window managers running (basically, restarts compiz). See if it starts remembering your settings. So far, it has mine.

Comment: @James I just tested this after a fresh restart. hot corner was dead again, ran `compiz --replace` in a terminal, and now the hot corner is active again. thanks, hoping this stays.

Comment: @Michael Butler Workarounds have stopped working with the switch to 12.10.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Main bug reports are at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/986208 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/858845.

## **For 12.04**

**Semi-Permanent solution** copied here:

- Run [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) from Terminal or Alt+F2
- Navigate to apps > compiz-1 > general > screen0 > options
- Edit the key: `active_plugins`
  [image: gconf Navigation Path]
- Move "Scale" to the bottom of the list.
- Move "Expo" to bottom right above "Scale" and underneath Unityshell.
  [image: active_plugins key]

I say "semi-permanent" because some software updates (Unity) may cause the plug-in order to get rearranged, so you may need to repeat these steps 2 or 3 times per month.

## **For 12.10 and 13.04:**

The above fix stopped working with the upgrade to **12.10** and continues on with 13.04. There are proposed solutions for 12.10 & 13.04 at the bug report link above, but so far nothing solid.

**Semi-Permanent solution** for 12.10:

- Run [dconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) from Terminal or Alt+F2
- Navigate to /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core
- Edit the key: `active-plugins`
  [image: dconf navigation path]
- Move 'scale' and 'expo' to last in the list.
  [image: active-plugins key]

Note that system updates may revert this fix and you may have to use dconf to fix it again.

***Please continue to contribute to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/858845) to get the problem fixed in 12.04 LTS, 12.10 and beyond.***

Comment: For at least one person, the dconf key in 12.10 is located at **/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins-with-set-keys** . I don't know if their configuration is different than a stock 12.10 download or not though.

Comment: Also works on 13.10.

Comment: I still have this bug in 14.04, but the solution no longer works. Instead it crashes everything. Neat.

Comment: I have the same problem, so I put: expo, scale, unityshell and works.

Answer (score 2):

For those experiencing this issue in 12.10 try this

Changing the order in the dconf key:

"/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins"

to read:

['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'decor', 'gnomecompat', 'resize', 'snap', 'move', 'regex', 'place', 'vpswitch', 'grid', 'widget', 'compiztoolbox', 'session', 'imgsvg', 'mousepoll', 'imgpng', 'animation', 'wall', 'unitymtgrabhandles', 'workarounds', 'ezoom', 'fade', 'unityshell', 'scale', 'expo']

Fixed the issue for me, in Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. I'm not sure if this is required but, for those that are saying it's not working for them, make sure you have "Ubuntu-Tweak" installed. I recall in researching this issue, coming across a claim that a dependent package installed with Ubuntu Tweak, corrects another issue with screen triggers being retained across reboots.

Also, I know this should be obvious, but if your machine won't do 3D acceleration these compiz plug-in's just plain don't work

Comment: Just an update it seems software updates change this setting back to the original ordering from time to time, requiring one to go back in and reset the ordering with scale and expo at the end. The last time I had to do this I was given some errors and had to go through resetting the order a few times before it finally took. It would seem the best way for this to be done would be with a script setting this order before each boot, unfortunately I don't know exactly how that would be done

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution is just running "Ubuntu Tweak" application once after every reboot. <strike>(Changing plugin order works too but it is temporary too. I need to rearrange them after reboot.)</strike>

Comment: that's odd, for me changing the plug-in order in gconf-editor fixes it mostly permanently even after reboots. Rarely the plug-in order gets changed back when there is a major update to Unity. So are you saying you just run Ubuntu Tweak and then close it, you don't have to change settings?

Comment: Yes exactly . I run Ubuntu Tweak and then close it . But you were right , i installed unity revamped i think that changed the order. After that i thought changing order does not work for me and never changed again, kept opening then closing ubuntu tweak . Now i changed the plugin order again and it works !! Thank you . and i am sorry for my half-wrong information !!

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/986208/comments/10) comment solved the problem for me. Just disable the "Launcher Capture Mouse" in "Ubuntu Unity plug-in -> Experimental".

Comment: Doesn't fix it for me in 12.10

Comment: In 14.04 this options is disabled by default but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @James was pretty detailed and the screenshots did help a lot. However, Compiz was still forgetting the settings. "UnityShell" keeps getting to the end of the list after every reboot and messing up scale and expo.

I was able to solve the issue by locking the positions of the keys. You can do this using CCSM.

Open CCSM (CompizConfig) and click on preference and then Plugin List. Uncheck "Automatic Plugin Sorting." Ensure that Scale is the last entry and expo just above that. If you are using Scale addon, make sure it goes below scale.

Now restart the computer and Scale and Expo will load. You can also check the order of keys in conf editor and ensure that they hold their positions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tested in 14.04 but it crashes compiz. Tried *[scale, expo, unityshell]* and *[expo, scale, unityshell]* but it failed in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In 14.04, running `nohup compiz --replace &` in a terminal solves my problem, but I still have to type it every time after a reboot. I tried manually ordering the plugins as the majority of answers here tell you to do, but it just crashes compiz.

Comment: if I do this, Yakuake will break and have to be restarted; the solution was to first load `metacity --replace` (I think this lets compiz properly end/cleanup) wait 3s and `compiz --replace`

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04 moving (in dconf) 'scale' and 'expo' AFTER 'unityshell' (so at the end of the list) causes the system to freeze completely after triggering scale (by hot corner or by key). Expo is seems to work.