# In 13.04 using Unity Tweak Tool hot corners stops working after reboot

Tags: unity, 13.04

I have 13.04 64 bit Ubuntu installed and I'm using Unity Tweak tool to enable hot corners everything works as it should as long as I don't reboot as soon as I do hotcorners stops working.  In order to get them functioning again I have to open the tweak tool and turn hotcorners off and then back on after every reboot.  This I admit isn't a huge issue but is annoying is there anyway to get hotcorners to work properly after reboot with out having to reset them every time?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04

Comment: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-restart-unity-and-compiz-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

Comment: This is a bug reported. M looking for a workaround as well.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1128041

Comment: here's the solution, which worked for me on 13.10:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/140759/scale-plugin-keeps-forgetting-hot-corner-settings-on-restart

Answer (score 3):

1. Install dconf-editor:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Run dconf-editor (don't use sudo as the changes wont affect your account)
3. Navigate to `org -> compiz -> profiles -> unity -> plugins -> core`.
4. Copy the field `active-plugins` into Gedit, and edit it so `unityshell` is the last item. Paste it back into dconf.
5. Restart your computer.

(Tried on **14.04**, it works.)

Comment: Mine already defaults to unityshell as last item, but problem still exists.

Comment: @kolslorr It could be that the "default" just sets it to the value it had on boot or something, I really wouldn't know. Could you check again? And try switching to the guest account - see if it has `unityshell` as the last one as well (remember not to use sudo).

Comment: solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well this might help, If you set the right bottom hotcorner to spread all windows, it will work even after reboot. I guess its because that is the only corner on the screen Ubuntu does not get to use with default launchers.

Comment: It resets the right corner as well for me. (14.04)

Answer (score 0):

in 14.04 for a **work around** what I did was write a bash script to set the hot corner edge valuse using **dconf**, but you will need to use dconf to find out what hot corner triggers you are using
you need to install **dconf-editor**, using the tree-structure you can work out the paths.

```
#!/bin/bash
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-edge "'|TopLeft'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-all-edge "'|BottomLeft'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/expo/expo-edge "'TopRight'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/show-desktop-edge "'|BottomRight'"
```

For expo it didn't have | in front

Then I ran this automatically script after logging in.

Answer (score -1):

I've had mixed luck with this, which used to fix this reliably in 12.04: [Scale plugin keeps forgetting hot corner settings on restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140759/scale-plugin-keeps-forgetting-hot-corner-settings-on-restart) :

> Run gconf-editor from Terminal or Alt+F2
>   Navigate to apps > compiz-1 > general > screen0 > options
>   Edit the key: active_plugins
>   Move "Scale" to the bottom of the list.
>   Move "Expo" to bottom right above "Scale" and underneath Unityshell.

Try moving Expo to after Scale at the absolute bottom in 12.10+