# Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty doesn't utilize hot corners after rebooting

Tags: unity

Everytime I reboot, I've to turn off and on hotcorners from `unity-tweak-tool`. Other wise hot corners don't work. Any fix??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This settings in in normal System Settings as well. Have you tried adjusting it there? Otherwise, it might be a bug. In that case, you should report it on Launchpad.net.

Comment: Where exactly is this setting in normal System Settings?
I worked around this bug in 13.10 like mentioned here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/309301/in-13-04-using-unity-tweak-tool-hot-corners-stops-working-after-reboot
but in 14.04 it really messes up my desktop when i hit a corner.

Comment: Same problem here. Is there any fix by now?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happended to me. But, first of all, after I upgraded to 14.04 I didn't have this problem, it happened like two days ago after an update. The point is that I solved it by applying a solution I once knew worked for 13.04. Its the following:

- Run the dconf-editor:

  ```
  $ dconf-editor
  ```

  (if you don't have it install it by: sudo apt-get install
  dconf-tools)
- In the pop-up window go to the list on the left and open "core", which you find in the following order:

  org -> compiz -> profiles -> unity -> plugins -> core
- Once selected "core", on the right find a key named "active-plugins", and change the order of the last three entries in
  the "Value" field, so that the last ones are 'unityshell', 'expo' and
  'scale'. For ease of the procedure, delete all the entries in the
  "Value" field, copy the following lines and paste them in the "Value"
  field:

  ['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'copytex', 'compiztoolbox', 'resize',
  'mousepoll', 'wall', 'widget', 'grid', 'imgpng', 'snap', 'move',
  'place', 'regex', 'vpswitch', 'animation', 'session',
  'unitymtgrabhandles', 'workarounds', 'fade', 'ezoom', 'unityshell',
  'expo', 'scale']
- Reboot.

Comment: I followed these instructions and now I have a blank screen.  How can I undo this by command line?

Comment: My entire computer is useless now.  I have to ctrl-alt f1 to even get a terminal.  I tried to follow unity and dconf reset protocols but they do not work without x11 active.  please, how do I reset this without x11 active?

Comment: following http://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load I was able to fix it.

Comment: There is some similar discussion/rationale for this approach [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1305438/comments/12), but after the comments above I'm reluctant to try this. Has anyone seen this approach work for them?

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I am very new to Linux (less 24 hours) but I've already met with this problem and found a solution.

Go to Startup Applications then ADD a new one, give it a name (doesn't matter what) and add this command:

```
compiz --replace
```

Then save. restart and enjoy.

Edit> doesnt work reliably, though.

Answer (score 2):

in 14.04 for a **work around** what I did was write a bash script to set the hot corner edge valuse using **dconf**, but you will need to use dconf to find out what hot corner triggers you are using
you need to install **dconf-editor**, using the tree-structure you can work out the paths.

```
#!/bin/bash
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-edge "'|TopLeft'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-all-edge "'|BottomLeft'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/expo/expo-edge "'TopRight'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/show-desktop-edge "'|BottomRight'"
```

For expo it didn't have | in front

Then I ran this automatically script after logging in, by adding it via "**Startup Applications**" you have to search for it in Unity Dash.

Comment: A good workaround for 14.04 !