# Configuration Editor does not show active plugins under Screen0

Tags: 14.04, compiz, configuration-management, scale-mode, expo-mode

I have Ubuntu 14.x installed in my system and use Expo and Scale plugins with their edge bindings extensively.
Earlier I used to use Configuration manager to set their place last in the list of active plugins so that they can work properly.

But now from few days before, they have stopped working and when I visit ConfigurationManager->apps->compiz-1->general->screen0 and click on options,
the list is presented in the right hand side does not contain option active-plugins.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I am asking something else, in my case the plugin list is not shown in the configuration editor at all.

Comment: in `dconf-editor`?

Comment: in gconf-editor. Earlier I made it to work by following instructions given here http://askubuntu.com/questions/140759/scale-plugin-keeps-forgetting-hot-corner-settings-on-restart. 

But now, in the same editor, the list of active plugins comes empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that the `gconf` settings have been migrated to the `dconf` database (See [When to use gconf vs dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91403/when-to-use-gconf-vs-dconf)).

You'll now find the **active-plugins** list in the dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[image]

You can edit this list and put both '**expo**' and '**scale**' plugins at the end to make them work the way you want.