# ubuntu 18.04 - Kb layout xkb-options are ignored after reboot

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

Using `Tweaks` to set keyboard layout works immediately. After reboot, although the settings I made are kept, `Tweaks` is ignored.

I find some solutions on the Internet, but all are related to older ubuntu versions(eg. [soltion for older ubuntu versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136445/ubuntu-tweak-tweaks-get-ignored-after-reboots)). I can't find these files mentioned in these solutions on ubuntu 18.04.

[UPDATE]
The changes I made are in `Keyboard & Mouse` > `Additional Layout Options` > `Alt/Win key behavior` and `Caps Lock behavior` shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of options I chosen]

The `ls -al ~/.config/dconf` command outputs:

```
total 24
drwx------  2 wen wen  4096 Aug 20 19:15 .
drwx------ 27 wen wen  4096 Aug 20 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen 13758 Aug 20 19:15 user
```

I tried `cd ~/.config/dconf && mv user user.bak` and reboot. Then the `ls -al ~/.config/dconf` command outputs:

```
total 32
drwx------  2 wen wen  4096 Oct 20 21:41 .
drwx------ 27 wen wen  4096 Aug 20 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen  4958 Oct 20 21:41 user
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen 14064 Oct 20 21:25 user.bak
```

A new `~/.config/dconf/user` file was created. It seems all settings were reset to default. So I used `Tweaks` to set again and it dose change the `~/.config/dconf/user` file.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen  5084 Oct 20 21:47 user
```

Reboot again, the `ls -al ~/.config/dconf` command outputs:

```
total 32
drwx------  2 wen wen  4096 Oct 20 21:57 .
drwx------ 27 wen wen  4096 Aug 20 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen  5084 Oct 20 21:57 user
-rw-r--r--  1 wen wen 14064 Oct 20 21:25 user.bak
```

The `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` command outputs:

```
['altwin:swap_alt_win', 'caps:ctrl_modifier']
```

The `cat /etc/default/keyboard` command outputs:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: What keyboard layout in Tweaks are you amending?

Comment: I selected `Alt is swapped with Win` and `Caps Lock is also a Ctrl` options. @Graham

Comment: Presumably under Additional Layout Options→Alt/Win key behaviour. Please edit your question to show a graphic of how you have set these options.

Comment: Yes, it is under `Additional Layout Options`. I have updated my question.@Graham

Comment: Have you tried just changing just one option to see if that persists? Maybe the two together are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I tried, but it still dosen't work after reboot.@Graham

Comment: Sure. I have added it into my qusetion.@GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: I tried this. The settings still doesn't work.@GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: I have edited my question. After I set keyboard through `Tweaks`, I checked the `~/.config/dconf/user` file and it indeed was changed. Then I rebooted and checked the `~/.config/dconf/user` file again. It's time stamp was changed. Is it possible that something overwirte this file when I reboot?@GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: I have updated my question. I also have checked the two commands' ouput after reboot. The output keeps the same but my settings dosen't work.

Comment: @Wen: That's a mystery. `xkb-options` are set as expected, they are not overridden at reboot, but still not effective? I'm lost.

Comment: It's still not effective. After reboot, the keyboard doesn't work as expected but the `Tweaks` shows as expected. If for example I cancel the `Alt is swapped with Win` option and choose it again, the keyboard will work as expected. It's pretty annoying. Anyway, thank you.@GunnarHjalmarsson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you may want to try to edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file and replace

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

with

```
XKBOPTIONS="altwin:swap_alt_win,caps:ctrl_modifier"
```

Comment: It works, thank you. BTW, are `/etc/default/keyboard` and `xkb-options` two different configration files? Is it possible that `xkb-options` is loaded first and then `/etc/default/keyboard` which has `XKBOPTIONS=""` leading to the final settings as default?

Comment: @Wen: It ought to be the other way around. `/etc/default/keyboard` contains system wide default settings affecting all users, while the dconf `xkb-options` key is user specific, and should override `/etc/default/keyboard`. So there is something with the configuration of your system which we haven't figured out; hence I consider it to be a workaround.

Comment: Solved for me, after Tweaks mysteriously started reverting this